# why is Helm installed Gitlab with Omniauth now displaying 500 error?

Tags: gitlab, keycloak, kubernetes-helm, openid-connect, omniauth

I have gitlab running in my kubernetes cluster, I also have the omniauth plugin installed to allow me to authenticate via Keycloak.

The below is the secret configuration for my gitlab omniauth secret

```
{ 
  name: 'openid_connect',
  label: 'Keycloak', # optional label for login button, defaults to "Openid Connect"
  icon: '',
  args: {
        name: 'openid_connect',
        scope: ['openid','profile','email'],
        response_type: 'code',
        issuer: 'https://<KEYCLOAK_ADDRESS>/auth/realms/<KEYCLOAK_REALM>',
        discovery: true,
        client_auth_method: 'query',
        uid_field: '',
        send_scope_to_token_endpoint: false,
        client_options: {
          identifier: 'KEYCLOAK_CLIENT',
          secret: 'KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_SECRET',
          redirect_uri: 'https://<GITLAB_ADDRESS>/users/auth/openid_connect/callback'
        }
  }
}
```

The gitlab pods in the cluster all seems to be running as shown below, i have tried to delete some of the pods to force a restart but that does not solve the problem.

[image]

Now when i click on the sign in with keycloak button i get the following and i'm not toally sure what changed.

[image]

**How do i debug this issue ? or resolve it. ?**

Comment: Do you have access to the Keycloak logs?

Comment: You are missing a comma after `icon: ''` Perhaps that could be a cause. Can you provide the relevant gitlab logs for the 500 error?

Comment: @sytech there is actually a comma in the config, i've updated the code above